# como pasar los datos de un div a otro

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, clone

Ocupe flexbox para hacer los div, con hover hago que se iluminen cuando paso el mouse por el
Pero trato de hacer que cuando pase el mouse y se iluminen, el caja grande se le pasen los valores del elemento iluminado. Asi es como lo llevo en js pero aun no me sale :C
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]]

'''

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('p');

var cajaGrande2 = document.querySelector('.numberCaja');
var cajaGrande = document.querySelector('.textGranCaja');
var cajaGrande3 = document.querySelector('.nameCaja');

elementos.forEach(function(elemento){
  elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    cajaGrande2.numberCaja = this.numberCaja;
    cajaGrande.textContent = this.textContent;
    cajaGrande3.nameCaja = this.nameCaja;
    var estilo = window.getComputedStyle(elemento);
    var color = estilo.getPropertyValue('color')
    cajaGrande.style.color = color;
  })
})
```

'''

Comment: Se te olvida copiar y pegar el código en tu pregunta. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar un [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tengo una posible respuesta para ti. Teniendo en cuenta que lo que quieres es copiar no solo el texto que tiene la etiqueta al que le pasas el hover si no que también quieres obtener los estilo, elaboré el siguiente script que puede que te ayude con lo que buscas. Te dejo el código aquí abajo y si es lo que necesitas me lo haces saber y yo te explico el código.

Código:

```js
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var cajaGrande = document.querySelector('.textGranCaja');

elementos.forEach(function(elemento){
  elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    cajaGrande.textContent = this.textContent;
    var estilo = window.getComputedStyle(elemento);
    var color = estilo.getPropertyValue('color')
    cajaGrande.style.color = color;
  })
})
```

```css
.textGranCaja{
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tableBox:nth-child(2){
  color: red;
}
.tableBox:nth-child(3){
  color: blue;
}
.tableBox:nth-child(4){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="granCaja">
  <p class="textGranCaja"></p>
</div>
<div class="tableBox">
    <div class="grupoBox">
      <p>H1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tableBox">
    <div class="grupoBox">
      <p>LI</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tableBox">
    <div class="grupoBox">
      <p>BE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puedes presionar en `ejecutar` allí arriba para poder probar el resultado si quieres. Espero sea lo que buscas.

**Explicación**

Primero declaro las variables `elementos` y `cajaGrande`, dichas variables contienen las etiquetas `p` (que es donde están los textos) y el elemento con la clase `textGranCaja` (que es donde se cambiará el elemento) respectivamente.

Luego, como son varias etiquetas `p` y las almaceno en una variable, esa variable pasa a ser un array entonces debo iterar sobre ese array, en este caso lo hice con un `forEach` ( [Si desconoces su uso, haz click aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), y dentro del mismo, mandé la instrucción de que a cada etiqueta `p` o sea `elemento`, al mover el mouse sobre ellas, cambiara el texto de `cajaGrande` con `textContent` y le pusiera el texto del elemento al que se le estaba haciendo hover. También declaré la variable `estilo` y le almacené los estilos de el elemento al que se le hace el hover, esto lo logré con el método `.getComputedStyle` ([Haz click aquí si lo desconoces](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)).

Luego en la variable `color` traje (por decirlo de alguna manera) el valor de la variable `estilo` y le pedí que solamente me devolviera el color, esto lo logré con `.getPropertyValue()`, esto quiere decir, que si tu elemento tiene más que solo el color, deberás hacer una variable para cada uno,  por ejemplo:

```js
var color = estilo.getPropertyValue("color")
var bg = estilo.getPropertyValue("background")
var border = estilo.getPropertyValue("border")
```

```css
p{
  color: red;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Luego de eso la ultima instrucción que le di, fue que el color del elemento `cajaGrande` sea igual al color que hay almacenado en la variable `color`.

Quizá se mire suuuper complicado y difícil de entender, pero es más fácil de lo que parece:D si analizas bien el código y amplías tu lógica de programador lo entenderás al 100%. Cabe resaltar que traté que todo fuera más automatizado con respecto a los estilos, pero no hallé forma:(, Espero te ayude y logres entender.

```css
.textGranCaja{
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tableBox:nth-child(2){
  color: red;
  background: blue;
}
.tableBox:nth-child(3){
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
.tableBox:nth-child(4){
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

**Solución 2:**

Podrías usar algo como lo siguiente:

```js
var tableBox = document.querySelectorAll(".tableBox")

tableBox.forEach(function(elemento){
  elemento.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
      document.querySelector(".granCaja").innerHTML=elemento.innerHTML
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="granCaja">
  <p class="textGranCaja"></p>
</div>
<div class="tableBox">
    <div class="grupoBox">
      <p>H1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tableBox">
    <div class="grupoBox">
      <p>LI</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tableBox">
    <div class="grupoBox">
      <p>BE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Que lo que hace es tomar el HTML del elemento al que se le da el hover, en este caso los `.tableBox` y los pega en `.granCaja`.

Comment: si hermano es justo lo que busco, muchas gracias. estoy tratando de encontrar informacion y porfin me salvaste hermano, muchas gracias!! y te tomo la palabra sino es mucha molestia sobre la explicacion hermano porfavor :)

Comment: Listo, te dejé la explicación en la respuesta, de paso te pido que si te ha servido y lo ves útil, le des un punto a favor y lo declares como la mejor respuesta para que a otros usuarios les pueda servir de la misma manera.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano me sirvió demasiado la información. Pero me surgio una duda mas si no es mucho abusar. Trate de seguir esa lógica. Pero al momento de pasar el mouse, solo lo hace en el elemento de la etiqueta p. Sabes hermano si hay alguno modo de poder hacer que todo lo del div se pase al otro div. lo dejo en una respuesta el codigo. Muchas gracias hermano

Comment: Claro, te dejé el código, pruebalo y me dices si te sirve.